# Using PATINDEX to find varying length patterns in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to pull floats out of some varchars, using PATINDEX() to spot them. I know in each varchar string, I'm only interested in the first float that exists, but they might have different lengths.

e.g.

```
'some text 456.09 other text'
'even more text 98273.453 la la la'
```

I would normally match these with a regex

```
  "[0-9]+[.][0-9]+"
```

However, I can't find an equivalent for the + operator, which PATINDEX accepts. So they would need to be matched (respectively) with:

```
'[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]' and '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Is there any way to match both of these example varchars with one single valid PATINDEX pattern?

Comment: You may need to go with regex. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I blogged about this a while ago.
[Extracting numbers with SQL server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server)

```
Declare @Temp Table(Data VarChar(100))

Insert Into @Temp Values('some text 456.09 other text')
Insert Into @Temp Values('even more text 98273.453 la la la')
Insert Into @Temp Values('There are no numbers in this one')

Select Left(
             SubString(Data, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', Data), 8000),
             PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(Data, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', Data), 8000) + 'X')-1)
From   @Temp
```

Comment: That expression will match **...**, which hardly is a float.

Answer (score 3):

Wildcards.

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%[0-9].[0-9]%[0-9]%','some text 456.09 other text')
SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%[0-9].[0-9]%[0-9]%','even more text 98273.453 la la la')
```

Comment: Fail: SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%[0-9].[0-9]%[0-9]%','some text 4.9 other text')

Comment: Not fail: SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%.%[0-9]%','some text 4.9 other text')

Comment: @Ben, I'm afraid this won't work because the string could have none float numbers in it that I'm not interested in. e.g. 'the number 2 then text 43.9 other text' for which this pattern would return: '2 then text 43.9'

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a shot. I feel your pain. Sybase back-end, which doesn't have SQL Server's bells and whistles, and a front-end that doesn't do regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to link to the clr to get regex support.  But if PATINDEX does not do what you need then regex was designed exactly for that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Comment: Note that later versions of SQL server refuse to load this external package on the excuse that the code is not a pure .NET assembly. [See this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15173120).

Comment: @Jerry You can get Regular Expressions rather easily by installing the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library (which I wrote, but the RegEx stuff is in the Free version). This library works in all versions of SQL Server, starting with SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Should be checked for robustness (what if you only have an int, for example), but this is just to put you on a track:

```
if exists (select routine_name from information_schema.routines where routine_name = 'GetFirstFloat')
    drop function GetFirstFloat
go

create function GetFirstFloat (@string varchar(max))
returns float
as
begin
    declare @float varchar(max)
    declare @pos int

    select @pos = patindex('%[0-9]%', @string)
    select @float = ''

    while isnumeric(substring(@string, @pos, 1)) = 1
    begin
        select @float = @float + substring(@string, @pos, 1)
        select @pos = @pos + 1
    end

    return cast(@float as float)
end
go


select dbo.GetFirstFloat('this is a string containing pi 3.14159216 and another non float 3 followed by a new fload 5.41 and that''s it')
select dbo.GetFirstFloat('this is a string with no float')
select dbo.GetFirstFloat('this is another string with an int 3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the pattern is going to be varied in length, you're not going to have a rough time getting this to work with PATINDEX. [There is another post that I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576683/replace-values-in-a-csv-string/9583457#9583457), which I've modified to accomplish what you're trying to do here. Will this work for you?

```
CREATE TABLE #nums (n INT)
DECLARE @i INT 
SET @i = 1
WHILE @i < 8000 
BEGIN
    INSERT #nums VALUES(@i)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

CREATE TABLE #tmp (
  id INT IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
  words VARCHAR(MAX) null
)

INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES('I''m looking for a number, regardless of length, even 23.258 long'),('Maybe even pi which roughly 3.14159265358,'),('or possibly something else that isn''t a number')

UPDATE #tmp SET words = REPLACE(words, ',',' ')

;WITH CTE AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rownum, ID, NULLIF(SUBSTRING(' ' + words + ' ' , n , CHARINDEX(' ' , ' ' + words + ' ' , n) - n) , '') AS word
    FROM #nums, #tmp
    WHERE ID <= LEN(' ' + words + ' ') AND SUBSTRING(' ' + words + ' ' , n - 1, 1) = ' ' 
    AND CHARINDEX(' ' , ' ' + words + ' ' , n) - n > 0),
    ids AS (SELECT ID, MIN(rownum) AS rownum FROM CTE WHERE ISNUMERIC(word) = 1 GROUP BY id)
SELECT CTE.rownum, cte.id, cte.word
FROM CTE, ids WHERE cte.id = ids.id AND cte.rownum = ids.rownum
```

The explanation and origin of the code is covered in more detail in the [origional post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576683/replace-values-in-a-csv-string/9583457#9583457)

Answer (score -2):

PATINDEX is not powerful enough to do that. You should use regular expressions.

SQL Server has Regular expression support since SQL Server 2005.

Comment: For Regex support in Sql Server 2005/08, installing additional modules is required (I believe) - but I would very much like to avoid doing so

Comment: PATINDEX is powerful enough to do this.  Please see my post.

Comment: @Mastros Sorry, but it isn't. It is possible that you can get a "good enough" solution using `PATINDEX`, but you cannot get a solution that handles any input. You need the ability to match optional characters (e.g. the `?` of regexp) to build a solution that works in the general case.

Comment: @Richard and Klas: Regular Expressions are supported, but not as built-in functions. RegEx requires using the CLR Integration (i.e. SQLCLR). Using any .NET / CLR functionality requires that you load an Assembly, but there are no pre-defined "modules". You need to either create the Assembly yourself or get a pre-built one. An example of a pre-built one is the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library (which I wrote, but the RegEx stuff is in the Free version).