# (Unfixable) Assembly exists on SQL Server 2014 but it claims it doesn't have it

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlclr

**Update:** this problem is not fixable: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/809697

I'm attempting to create a SQL CLR assembly with .net 4.5 and it's telling me it's missing `system.servicemodel` (even though it's in the .net assembly folders):

```
Assembly 'MySQLCLRProject' references assembly 'system.servicemodel, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.
```

So I manually add a 4.5,4.5.1,4.5.2 `System.ServiceModel.dll` to the project folder, then it tells me it's missing `system.servicemodel.internals`:

```
Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.servicemodel, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.
Msg 10301, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Assembly 'MySQLCLRProject' references assembly 'system.servicemodel.internals, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.
```

So I add a 4.6 `System.ServiceModel.dll` it will tell me it's missing `system.xaml`:

```
Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.servicemodel, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.
Msg 10301, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Assembly 'MySQLCLRProject' references assembly 'system.xaml, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.
```

After I add system.xaml (4.5-4.6.1), it tells me this:

```
Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.servicemodel, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.
Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.xaml, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.
Msg 6218, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'MySQLCLRProject' failed because assembly 'System.Xaml' failed verification. Check if the referenced assemblies are up-to-date and trusted (for external_access or unsafe) to execute in the database. CLR Verifier error messages if any will follow this message
[ : System.Xaml.AttachableMemberIdentifier::ToString][mdToken=0x6000009][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachableMemberIdentifier::Equals][mdToken=0x6000006][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachableMemberIdentifier::GetHashCode][mdToken=0x6000008][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachableMemberIdentifier::Equals][mdToken=0x6000007][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachableMemberIdentifier::.ctor][mdToken=0x6000001][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachableMemberIdentifier::get_MemberName][mdToken=0x6000002][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachableMemberIdentifier::get_DeclaringType][mdToken=0x6000003][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachableMemberIdentifier::op_Inequality][mdToken=0x6000004][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachableMemberIdentifier::op_Equality][mdToken=0x6000005][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachablePropertyServices::.cctor][mdToken=0x6000010][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachablePropertyServices::TryGetProperty[T]][mdToken=0x600000f][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachablePropertyServices::GetAttachedPropertyCount][mdToken=0x600000a][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachablePropertyServices::CopyPropertiesTo][mdToken=0x600000b][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachablePropertyServices::RemoveProperty][mdToken=0x600000c][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml.AttachablePropertyServices::SetProperty][mdToken=0x600000d][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Xaml....
```

I've searched all over and couldn't find anything to address this problem. I've even recreated the project entirely with .net 4.5 and it still giving me problems.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are attempting to use an unsupported .NET Framework library: `ServiceModel`. This library did work in SQL Server 2005, 2008, and 2008 R2. However, since it is not in the "supported" list, it is not guaranteed to work across all .NET Framework upgrades. It used to be a pure-MSIL Assembly but then they changed it to be a mixed-mode Assembly, and those cannot be loaded into SQL Server.

This issue has been documented on Stack Overflow here:

- [Register CLR function (WCF based) in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173120/register-clr-function-wcf-based-in-sql-server-2012)
- [SQL CLR - Migration from 2008 R2 to 2012.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567028/sql-clr-migration-from-2008-r2-to-2012)

More info here:

- [SQL Server: "CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'Test' failed because assembly 'Test' is malformed or not a pure .NET assembly."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653838/sql-server-create-assembly-for-assembly-test-failed-because-assembly-test/36654479#36654479)
- [SQL Server custom CLR fails with error "Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598524/sql-server-custom-clr-fails-with-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-o/31615762#31615762)

Comment: Looks like your post here is the solution to the problem: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149292/bringing-web-service-data-into-sql-server/149349#149349?newreg=15bc9df154ea4a56a84ce016c2492f33

I'd have to consume the service with `httpwebrequest` but the problem is using `xmldocument` which is where the problem is I believe(xml seralization uses assemblies that's not supported in sql server 2012).

Comment: @sojim2 No, [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) is just fine. I have used it before. It exists in `System.Xml` which is in the [supported list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx).

Comment: I'm new to consuming WCF manually, would something like this work with Rest WCF? https://www.stickler.de/en/information/code-snippets/httpwebrequest-post-data All I would need to change is use XML reader instead of streamreader.

Comment: @sojim2 I would not use the example code at the link you provided (on stickler.de). It is bad code: doesn't clean up disposable resources, uses wrong encoding (i.e. ASCII instead of something like UTF-8 or something else). But in a general sense, you would probably need to do the `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` into a string that you then use when creating the `XmlDocument`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the UTF-8 encoding, this will save us huge headache down the line.