# Assembly dependency in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

When I register the assembly `System.ServiceModel.dll` I get this warning message:

[image: Registering System.ServiceModel.dll]

After that I am trying to register `Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge.dll` and get this warning:

[image: Registering Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge.dll]

Answer (score 0):

What directory / folder are you trying to pull in those DLLs from? You should only need to create the **ServiceModel** Assembly. This will require that the Database be set to `TRUSTWORTHY ON` and that you create the Assembly as `UNSAFE`.

That being said, you would be better off finding an entirely different approach given that very limited nature of what you are building. SQLCLR is a very restricted environment and does not allow for mixed-mode Assemblies; only pure MSIL Assemblies are allowed. In .NET Framework versions 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5, the **ServiceModel** library was pure MSIL so importing it did work. However, starting with .NET Framework v 4.0, **ServiceModel** changed to be a mixed-mode DLL and hence cannot be imported into SQL Server starting with SQL Server 2012 (i.e. the first version of SQL Server to be linked to CLR v 4.0 which uses .NET Framework versions 4.0 through the current 4.7 (I think)). And there is no fix outside of re-writing the code to no longer reference **ServiceModel**. Please see my answer here for more details on that:

[(Unfixable) Assembly exists on SQL Server 2014 but it claims it doesn't have it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313954/unfixable-assembly-exists-on-sql-server-2014-but-it-claims-it-doesnt-have-it/40314364#40314364)