# Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view it is not full-text indexed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to fetch all records which contain `.`

At the moment I use this SQL:

```
  select * from dbo.mytable
    where CONTAINS(Location, '.')
```

but I receive this error:

```
Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view it is not full-text indexed.
```

I cannot set `column full text indexed` as I do not have high privilege.

Any idea how to circumnavigate this problem?

Comment: Please add a comment when down-voting. Glad to edit my question.

Comment: How about using `PATINDEX` sort of [that way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772566/using-patindex-to-find-varying-length-patterns-in-t-sql)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `CONTAINS` the column needs to be full-text indexed.

If you don't, or can't, then you can search for data containing a `.` using `LIKE`

```
 where Location LIKE '%.%'
```