# Parsing a URL to find a varying length string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, parsing, url

I have a string in multiple URLs starting with two characters followed by between 1-6 numbers e.g. 'SO123456' This string is rarely in the same position within the URL. Following the string is either .html or whitespace.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(URL,PATINDEX('%SO[0-9]%',URL),8)

FROM Table

WHERE URL LIKE '%SO[0-9]%'
```

This code returns 'SO12.htm' if the string is shorter than 8 characters.

Not all of the URLs have this string, and if that's the case then I still need the query to produce 'Null'.

I'm trying to return the exact length of the string. Can anyone help me with a way to solve this please? Can you find the length of a wildcard string to use within the substring so that only the exact string length is returned?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772566/using-patindex-to-find-varying-length-patterns-in-t-sql

Comment: Not sure how to relate this to my problem

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9778647/1015327) shows how to extract a substring matching a pattern from a string. The same should work for you. Then take the length of that string.

Comment: This works for the URLs where my string is the first numeric character. Do you have any idea how to apply this to exactly the string I need? Thanks

Comment: Of course, you must use *your own* pattern, but apart from that it should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite elaborated, but as a hint to get you started:

```
patindex = PATINDEX('%SO[0-9]%',URL) -> Index of the start of the pattern
charindex = CHARINDEX('.html', URL, patindex ) -> Index of the first '.html' after the start of the pattern.
patternLen = charindex - patindex
```

So something like the following may work:

```
SELECT
  CHARINDEX('.html', URL,
    PATINDEX('%SO[0-9]%',URL)
  ) -
  PATINDEX('%SO[0-9]%',URL)
FROM ...
```

---

> Not all of the URLs have this string, and if that's the case then I
>   still need the query to produce 'Null'.

-> Outer (self) join:

```
SELECT
  allUrls.URL,
  CHARINDEX('.html', u.URL, PATINDEX('%SO[0-9]%',u.URL) ) - PATINDEX('%SO[0-9]%', u.URL) -- Same as above
FROM MyTable allUrls
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable u
  ON allUrls.URL = u.URL
  AND u.URL LIKE '%SO[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the length of the column first dude.
Here's the code

```
SELECT CASE LEN(URL) -- Check the length of URL column
WHEN > 8 THEN SUBSTRING(URL,PATINDEX('%SO[0-9]%',URL),8)
ELSE -- do your stuff
END as 'example'
FROM Table
```

Comment: Every URL is greater than 8 characters, the 8 is the maximum number of characters the string I'm interested can be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Select case when patindex('%SO[0-9]&',URL) = 0 then null else substring(URL, patindex('%SO[0-9]&',URL),8)

From Table