# How to parse a date from text in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, substring

I already have code for pulling formatted dates from text fields such as the example below:

```
    SUBSTRING(REPLACE(al.Comments + '.','.','{br}'), 
        PATINDEX('%Visit Date%',REPLACE(al.Comments+'.','.','{br}')) + 13, 
        PATINDEX('%{br}%',
            SUBSTRING(REPLACE(al.Comments+'.','.','{br}'), 
                PATINDEX('%Visit Date%', 
                    REPLACE(al.Comments+'.','.','{br}')) + 13, 14))-1))
```

The date is inserted programmatically into a Comments field of internal software.
My question is how to pull a date from the same table and column (al.Comments) when the comment and the date are input manually by an end user.

Possible ways an end user might input a date would be:

- m/d/yy
- mm/dd/yy
- m/d/yyyy
- mm/dd/yyyy
- m/d (assume the same year as current year)
- mm/d (assume the same year as current year)
- m/dd (assume the same year as current year)
- mm/dd (assume the same year as current year)

Things to note

- This is SQL 2008
- SQL CLR and Regex are not possible
- I cannot request that the software be updated for this process
- I understand that this is complex and it may not be possible to account for all cases so anything that approximates as many of the possible end user inputs will be acceptable

In the case of this date (unlike the sample I posted above) I will be looking for a keyword of 'proposed' followed by a date and any other number of characters.  Below is a sample of some of what I see in my results set for al.Comments:

[image: Sample Results]

I am creating a tracker in SSRS and among many other tables I am creating a result set that would allow me to track any proposed dates within a week or less of the date proposed. Most of my other result sets are either using datetime stamps or are pulling from programmatically added dates like the sample I posted.  I can't figure out a way in SQL to pull this date so I can create a column for my results set/SSRS tracker

**EDIT:**

I have loosely called this a 'form' when in fact it is internal software that has a dev team that DOES have access to it, but this is part of a process and a database that is complex and has a lot of history.  This department is one of many, all of our software outside of standard Google and Microsoft software is created internally.  We have dozens of pieces of software that are all inter related and tied to each other in a very large, very complex database.  I didn't write the software and the team that is over this software has bigger fish to fry that to add a field for my tracker to work.

This department is experiencing growing pains (a good thing) and just restructured all job functions last month.  I work for a reports team and I was assigned a report to develop to track jobs assigned to technicians in the field.

If I have to write a complex, long SUBSTRING I will.  Department standards do require that my queries are optimized and very fast.  So I was looking for a way to query the database and parse text as simply as possible.

**EDIT 2 (Testing Alan Burstein's answer below)**

I have been testing Alan's answer and it is close.  I could use a little help getting to the finish line.  Below are some snippets of test code and the results I am getting.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(al.Comments,PATINDEX('%proposed%',al.Comments)+9,17)  [col1]
INTO
    #test1
```

Followed by this code:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN col1 LIKE '%/%-%/%' THEN SUBSTRING(#test1.col1,PATINDEX('%/%',#test1.col1)-2,5)
    WHEN col1 LIKE '%/%,%/%' THEN SUBSTRING(#test1.col1,PATINDEX('%/%',#test1.col1)-2,5)
    WHEN col1 LIKE '%/%/%' THEN SUBSTRING(#test1.col1,PATINDEX('%/%/%',#test1.col1)-2,12)
    END
FROM
    #test1
```

Sample of the results I am getting is below this - I haven't done the CAST yet because I have some leading spaces and trailing text I need to figure out how to exclude - thoughts?

[image: sample 2]

This will be in a temp table and a LEFT JOIN so NULLs are fine.

**EDIT 3 - How I got it to work w/o a function**

I marked Alan's answer as correct because it worked when tested but I was told no functions by our Data Team Lead. I found another solution on [StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772566/using-patindex-to-find-varying-length-patterns-in-t-sql) Read the second answer by G Mastros.  I applied this next query to my previous one to strip out the offending characters:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(#test2.col1, PATINDEX('%[0-9/]%', #test2.col1), 10),
            PATINDEX('%[^0-9/]%', SUBSTRING(#test2.col1, PATINDEX('%[0-9/]%', #test2.col1), 10) + 'X')-1)
FROM #test2
```

The new results:

[image]

Comment: Would there be a risk of the forward slashes showing up in the comment when NOT in reference to a date?

Comment: I cannot for see one, especially not when the 'proposed' keyword is being used.  This is at best a work around to help out a department where I work.  They are implementing this procedure to adding these comments so a tracker can be made  to help with their workflow.  If anything breaks it then it will be on the end user unfortunately.  This tracker is also only checking for comments in documents with a CURRENT status set a certain way so older comments wouldn't be an issue

Comment: Sounds like you probably just need a different SUBSTRING and PATINDEX combo for each different expected format then

Comment: For a comprehensive/robust solution we would need to know the restrictions or variations imposed on the user input. It would appear that there is format which follows: "via email, proposed ....".
what else can you tell us.?  
how many possible dates, etc.?

Comment: Free form comment field. Restrictions will come down to user training to input a certain way but I wanted something more robust that might catch  multiple input styles on dates.  It is a difficult task as the tracker would be a great tool for the department but if I require too many restrictions or if the tool is perceived as 'useless' because a lot of dates are missed then it will go unused.

Comment: How sure are you there will never be a british, german, south american, etc person put in a date in the d/m/yy format?

Comment: @Joel 100% certain.  Internal form for a department of <100 persons

Comment: "Free form comment field. Restrictions will come down to user training to input a certain way " this is sure to collect many entries that will not conform to a quick solution.  
as this is an " Internal form " I would assume you have access to it. I would just modify the form so that it inputs a date(s) type and you can store in a datetime field.
Otherwise you will have to write a complex UDF utilizing PATINDEX, etc.

Comment: edited my question to clarify my need and the reason the field will not be changed in the near future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (col1 varchar(20));
INSERT @table VALUES 
('1/2/01'),('11/12/99'),('5/5/2013'),('09/13/2003'),
('2/4'),('12/4'),('8/11'),('12/12');

SELECT *, newvalue = 
  CASE 
    WHEN col1 LIKE '%/%/%' THEN CAST(col1 AS date) 
    ELSE col1+'/'+this.yr
  END

FROM @table
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (CAST(YEAR(getdate()) AS varchar(4)))) this(yr);
```

Returns:

```
col1                 yr   newvalue
-------------------- ---- ----------
1/2/01               2018 2001-01-02
11/12/99             2018 1999-11-12
5/5/2013             2018 2013-05-05
09/13/2003           2018 2003-09-13
2/4                  2018 2018-02-04
12/4                 2018 2018-12-04
8/11                 2018 2018-08-11
12/12                2018 2018-12-12
```

Easy peasy lemon squeezy.

---

**UPDATE BASED ON OP'S UPDATE**

One easy way to extract the dates would be to use PatternSplitCM; code below:

```
-- Function by Chris Morris, read more here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PatternSplitCM
(
       @List                VARCHAR(8000) = NULL
       ,@Pattern            VARCHAR(50)
) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS RETURN
    WITH numbers AS (
      SELECT TOP(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@List), 0))
       n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      FROM
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) g (n))

    SELECT
      ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(n)),
      Item = SUBSTRING(@List,MIN(n),1+MAX(n)-MIN(n)),
      [Matched]
     FROM (
      SELECT n, y.[Matched], Grouper = n - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY y.[Matched],n)
      FROM numbers
      CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT [Matched] = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@List,n,1) LIKE @Pattern THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) y
     ) d
     GROUP BY [Matched], Grouper;
```

Here's some updated sample data with the dates buried in the text along with code to demonstrate how you could extract the "dates":

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (col1 varchar(100));
INSERT @table VALUES 
('blah blah 1/2/01 xxxx'),('my name is fred and today is: 11/12/99'),
('5/5/2013 is the day I met Fred'),('The due date is 09/13/2003!!!'),
('This little piggy... ((2/4))'),('Call me on 12/4 at 10:30PM'),
('8/11 is the day after August 10th'),('Really?!?! 12/12 is the best?');

SELECT
  t.col1,
  ps.Item
FROM @table t
CROSS APPLY dbo.PatternSplitCM(t.col1,'[0-9/]') ps
WHERE [Matched] = 1 AND Item LIKE '%[0-9]/[0-9]%';
```

**Returns:**

```
col1                                        Item
------------------------------------------- -----------
blah blah 1/2/01 xxxx                       1/2/01
my name is fred and today is: 11/12/99      11/12/99
5/5/2013 is the day I met Fred              5/5/2013
The due date is 09/13/2003!!!               09/13/2003
This little piggy... ((2/4))                2/4
Call me on 12/4 at 10:30PM                  12/4
8/11 is the day after August 10th           8/11
Really?!?! 12/12 is the best?               12/12
```

Next you turn this into a subquery and apply my original logic like so.

**Updated solution:**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (col1 varchar(100));
INSERT @table VALUES 
('blah blah 1/2/01 xxxx'),('my name is fred and today is: 11/12/99'),
('5/5/2013 is the day I met Fred'),('The due date is 09/13/2003!!!'),
('This little piggy... ((2/4))'),('Call me on 12/4 at 10:30PM'),
('8/11 is the day after August 10th'),('Really?!?! 12/12 is the best?');

SELECT original = col1, newvalue =
  CASE 
    WHEN dt.item LIKE '%/%/%' THEN CAST(dt.item AS date) 
    ELSE dt.item+'/'+this.yr
  END
FROM
    (
  SELECT
    t.col1,
    ps.Item
  FROM @table t
  CROSS APPLY dbo.PatternSplitCM(t.col1,'[0-9/]') ps
  WHERE [Matched] = 1 AND Item LIKE '%[0-9]/[0-9]%'
) dt
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (CAST(YEAR(getdate()) AS varchar(4)))) this(yr);
```

**Returns:**

```
original                                    newvalue
------------------------------------------- ----------
blah blah 1/2/01 xxxx                       2001-01-02
my name is fred and today is: 11/12/99      1999-11-12
5/5/2013 is the day I met Fred              2013-05-05
The due date is 09/13/2003!!!               2003-09-13
This little piggy... ((2/4))                2018-02-04
Call me on 12/4 at 10:30PM                  2018-12-04
8/11 is the day after August 10th           2018-08-11
Really?!?! 12/12 is the best?               2018-12-12
```

Comment: I will test this on existing data and get back with your answer.  Thank you

Comment: Nice! This will do nicely once you are able to tease out the "dates" from the comments field.

Comment: @Alan and others, see my edited question with some test snippets.  Thanks

Comment: @DRT Note my update above; see if that works for you.

Comment: This works so I am marking as answered for anyone else that has a similar question.  Won't work for me as I was just told 'no' to adding a function on our servers.  I appreciate the help, I think I will just rework this and come at it a different way.

Comment: NOTE: Edit 3 has another solution that I found worked in my situation.  Again thanks for the help!