# How do I merge data from several rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-view

Here is my situation:

TABLE PEOPLE (code, name, + other fields that are identical for records with same code)

```
1;John Wayne
2;Jack Smith
2;Jill Smith
3;Bill Peyton
3;Gill Peyton
3;Billy Peyton
```

The result I would like:

VIEW PEOPLE (code, name, + other fields that are identical for records with same code)

```
1;John Wayne
2;Jack Smith Jill Smith
3;Bill Peyton Jill Peyton Billy Peyton
```

Can some one please help me create a view that would give me this result?
The point is merging rows with same "code" and merge names in column "name". All the other fields are 100% identical for rows with same "code".

Thank you.

Comment: i tried with group by but i lack sql skills :/

Comment: This has been asked so many times. Do a quick search with the tags sql-server and group-concat

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mimic group_concat() combined with group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298805/mimic-group-concat-combined-with-group)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return multiple values in one column (T-SQL)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122942/how-to-return-multiple-values-in-one-column-t-sql)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Possible Pivot Solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791247/sql-server-possible-pivot-solution)

Comment: Check this link http://explainextended.com/2010/06/21/group_concat-in-sql-server/
In mySQL exists a function that do exactly what you want, but in sqlServer it's more difficult.. you have to "emulate" that function

Comment: thanks to all that tried to help. Sorry for the duplicate i was not aware of group_concat. All i had was a problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Code,

       ( SELECT Name + ' '

           FROM Table1 t2

          WHERE t2.Code = t1.Code

          ORDER BY Name

            FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Name

      FROM Table1 t1

      GROUP BY Code ;
```

Comment: This works up until there are special xml characters in the name. You should use `.value` in conjunction with the `XML PATH` method to avoid these errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031204/does-t-sql-have-an-aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings/5031297#5031297

Comment: Thank you very much!!! May you hit the jackpot and get laid several times on this loveely friday ;)